# How to properly use conditionak operator in Swift

Tags: swift, conditional-operator

I want to rewrite the below code to use the conditional operator:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
  cell.indentationLevel = kIndentFDA
} else {
  cell.indentationLevel = kIndentCompleted
}
```

But when I write this:

```
indexPath.row == 0 ? cell.indentationLevel = kIndentFDA : cell.indentationLevel = kIndentCompleted
```

I get this compiler warning:

> "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'Int'"

Comment: what does the warning say?

Comment: `cell.indentationLevel = indexPath.row == 0 ? kIndentFDA : kIndentCompleted`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the warning it but it probably can't figure out the order to apply the operators. This should work.

cell.indentationLevel = indexPath.row == 0 ? kIndentFDA : kIndentCompleted

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you don't understand what the ternary operator *is*. It isn't for performing assignments within the branches; the branches are not *executable statements*. Rather, the branches are *evaluated expressions*; thus, you use the ternary operator in the rvalue of an assignment and the branch values themselves are what is assigned.

So, you are writing this (which is nonsense):

```
indexPath.row == 0 ? cell.indentationLevel = kIndentFDA : cell.indentationLevel = kIndentCompleted
```

What you mean is:

```
cell.indentationLevel = indexPath.row == 0 ? kIndentFDA : kIndentCompleted
```

Comment: Might be worthwhile to explain the different between statements and expressions

Comment: @Alexander Thanks, at least worthwhile using that terminology. Excellent idea.

Comment: `a = b` is (if I understand the grammar correctly), a binary expression using the assignment operator which does not return a value, i.e. the value is `Void`. A conditional expression like `x == 0 ? (y = 0) : (z = 1)` *does* compile if you set the parentheses. I agree of course that one "would not do that", but the immediate compiler error seems to be caused by precedence, not by "statement vs. expression".

Comment: @MartinR Yes, good point; of course I thought of the fact that an assignment can have a value, and in some languages it is the value assigned, but I'm not sure how to incorporate that point. You might post a more rigorous answer, or we could just let your comment stand as a corrective.

Comment: I just found a detailed answer and closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @MartinR excellent, thanks